How to update mui slider value with input field?
MUI slider running with min and max value with
const minVal = 8; const maxVal = 255;
<Slider
  value={range}
  min={minVal}
  max={maxVal}
  onChange={handleSliderChange}
  valueLabelDisplay="auto"
/>

At the same time, show input field the result in percentage for both Min Percentage and Max Percentage.
There is function on both input fields which is change range position by entering percentage in the input fields which is not working as expecting.
<TextField
  label="Min Percentage"
  value={minInput}
  onChange={handleMinInputChange}
  variant="outlined"
/>
<TextField
  label="Max Percentage"
  value={maxInput}
  onChange={handleMaxInputChange}
  variant="outlined"
/>

When typing value, it is not effecting, which is the issue with current code.
Demo :


https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/basicpopoverwitharrow-forked-5q7ydt?file=%2Fdemo.js%3A21%2C41
I hope it will work for you I have updated some changes

<TextField value is percentage. The updating percentage value in <TextField should reflect in slider as valuer. The Demo works well, but not able to update second time.

I have provided a CodeSandbox link. There is an issue where the focus is lost when updating the onChange event. Please fix that issue. I have updated the text field to handle range selection updates.
